# C++ function dll is returning wrong parameters on Dart FFI

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, struct, dll

I'm trying to consume an DLL (specifically the futronic SDK) through Dart FFI, but I'm having problems execute the **enroll** function, you can see the C++ code below.

```
typedef DGT32 FTRAPI_RESULT// = unsigned long;

define FTRAPI __stdcall

typedef DGTVOID *FTR_USER_CTX // = void;

typedef UDGT32 FTR_PURPOSE // = unsigned long;

typedef struct FTRPACK
{
UDGT32 dwSize; // Length of data in bytes.
DGTVOID *pData; // Data pointer.
} FTR_DATA, *FTR_DATA_PTR;

/*

* FTREnroll - creates the fingerprint template for the desired purpose.
* 
* Parameters:
* FTR_USER_CTX UserContext - optional caller-supplied value that is passed to callback
*                              functions. This value is provided for convenience in
*                              application design.
* 
* FTR_PURPOSE Purpose - the purpose of template building. This value designates the
*                         intended way of further template usage and can be one of the
*                         following:
* 
*                         FTR_PURPOSE_ENROLL - the created template is suitable for both
*                         identification and verification purpose.
* 
*                         FTR_PURPOSE_IDENTIFY - corresponding template can be used only
*                         for identification as an input for the FTRSetBaseTemplate function.
* 
* FTR_DATA_PTR pTemplate - pointer to a result memory buffer. The space for this buffer
*                            must be reservered by a caller. Maximum space amount can be
*                            determined through the FTRGetParam call with the
*                            FTR_PARAM_MAX_TEMPLATE_SIZE value of the first argument.
* 
* Returns result code.
* FTR_RETCODE_OK - success.
  */
  FTRAPIPREFIX FTRAPI_RESULT FTRAPI FTREnroll( FTR_USER_CTX UserContext, FTR_PURPOSE Purpose, FTR_DATA_PTR pTemplate );
```

Dart code:

```
typedef FTREnrollC = Int Function(FTR_USER_CTX, FTR_PURPOSE, Pointer<FTR_DATA>);
typedef FTREnroll = int Function(FTR_USER_CTX, int, Pointer<FTR_DATA>);

class FTR_DATA extends Struct {
@Uint32()
external int dwSize;
external Pointer<Void> pData;
}

typedef FTRPurpose = int;

class FutronicController {
  static final _ffiLibrary = DynamicLibrary.open('assets/dll/FTRAPI.dll');

  static int maxTemplateSize = 0;
  static Pointer<Void>? voidPointerResult;

  static Pointer<FTR_DATA>? pTemplate;

  static int initialize() {
    final FTRInitialize initialize = _ffiLibrary
        .lookup<NativeFunction<FTRInitializeC>>('FTRInitialize')
        .asFunction();
    int result = initialize();
    getParam(parametro: FTR_PARAM_MAX_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
    int setParamRes = FutronicController.setParam(parametro: 4, valor: 1);
    maxTemplateSize =
        PointerConvertions.voidToInt(voidPointer: voidPointerResult!);
    return result;
  }

  static int terminate() {
    final FTRTerminate initialize = _ffiLibrary
        .lookup<NativeFunction<FTRTerminateC>>('FTRTerminate')
        .asFunction();
    return initialize();
  }

  static int getParam({required FTRParam parametro}) {
    voidPointerResult = calloc.allocate(sizeOf<Pointer<Void>>());
    final FTRGetParam getParam = _ffiLibrary
        .lookup<NativeFunction<FTRGetParamC>>('FTRGetParam')
        .asFunction();
    return getParam(parametro, voidPointerResult!);
  }

  static int setParam({required FTRParam parametro, required int valor}) {
    Pointer<Int32> valueP = calloc.allocate(sizeOf<Int32>());
    valueP.value = valor.toUnsigned(32);
    final FTRSetParam setParam = _ffiLibrary
        .lookup<NativeFunction<FTRSetParamC>>('FTRSetParam')
        .asFunction();
    return setParam(parametro, valor.toUnsigned(32));
  }

  static int enroll({required FTRPurpose purpose}) {
    Pointer<FTR_DATA> data =
        calloc.allocate<FTR_DATA>(maxTemplateSize.toUnsigned(32));

    final FTREnroll enroll = _ffiLibrary
        .lookup<NativeFunction<FTREnrollC>>('FTREnroll')
        .asFunction();

    return enroll(nullptr, purpose.toUnsigned(32), data);
  }
}
```

I've tried to change type of int to `Uint64`, `Uint8`, change data to `nullptr`, `purpose.toSigned(32)`, change `Pointer<FTR_DATA>` to `Pointer<Void>` but just give me wrong arguments.

3: `FTRCode.FTR_RETCODE_INVALID_ARG`